# Upload an excel file using Cypress

Tags: excel, file-upload, encoding, xlsx, cypress

I using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload package for the file upload. 
When I try to upload an excel (xlsx, xls) I get an error about the encoding.

> [cypress-file-upload error]: "encoding" is not valid.
>   Please look into docs to find supported "encoding" values

I have the following code:

```
const fileName = 'file_example_XLSX_1000.xlsx'
cy.fixture('files used for testing/file_example_XLSX_1000.xlsx').then(fileContent => {
cy.get('#file').upload({ fileContent, fileName, mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', encoding: 'UTF - 8', }){ subjectType: 'input' }})
```

Answer (score 1):

Encoding should be `UTF-8` not `UTF - 8`.

Answer (score 1):

Capitalization and whitespace matter.

Consider `utf8` and `utf-8` - these two are different.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Arguments